# How to create animated beam sprite

Tags: sprite-kit

I am new to coding, so am unfamiliar with many techniques etc, so please bear with!

I was wondering how you would go about recreating the effect seen in 'God of light' (http://wpuploads.appadvice.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/IMG_5498.jpeg), specifically the animated beams of light, with the awesome 'energy' look to them. In my SpriteKit game, the player reflects a beam (of light) using mirrors they draw. I am currently creating the beam using a CGPath as this lets me change its length easily, and have finished the code for the game without textures and just using SKSpriteNodes and shapes etc but I am clueless as to how I would go about adding an animated texture to the beam, such as the one in God of Light. If anyone would be willing to share any ideas as to the basic plan they would use to go about creating this effect I would be very appreciative!

Sorry its a little vague, but I haven't begun giving the beam a texture yet, and literally have no idea how to go about it.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you could either try to use particle effects.. Or if you're more advanced shaders

Answer (score 0):

I would use a separate animation program such as After Effects to create the the animation effect you want and export a series of keyframes. Then I would place the keyframes into an atlas and use `SKAction animateWithTextures` to animate them. Here is an excellent tutorial on it: Sprite Kit Tutorial: Animations and Texture Atlases: http://www.raywenderlich.com/45152/sprite-kit-tutorial-animations-and-texture-atlases